# Changing size of Dojo Filtering Select via CSS in XPages

Tags: dojo, xpages

I just want to change the size of Dojo Filtering Select design element via CSS.
I tried manual or CSS File. It did not work.

`<xe:djFilteringSelect id="djselect1" value="#{document1.Language}" style="min-height: 8px;height:8.px;"></xe:djFilteringSelect>`
[image: Dojo Filtering Select in red rectangle]
Any suggestion is important 
Cumhur Ata

[image: Dojo Filtering Select Menu]

Comment: The best suggestion I can think of is to open this in Chrome Dev Tools. Looks at the box model and CSS and try changing the CSS from the specific element out to the container.  This will likely lead to finding which element to change. Once you figure out this, then you can add it to your CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Bootstrap theme you need to adjust the arrow button too.

This works for me:

```css
.dbootstrap .dijitTextBox {
    height: 24px;
}
.dbootstrap .dijitComboBox .dijitButtonNode.dijitArrowButton {
    height: 22px;
}
.xsp.dbootstrap .dijitInputContainer {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.dbootstrap .dijitComboBox input.dijitArrowButtonInner {
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
.dbootstrap .dijitMenuItem {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

Comment: i could not find the name of Dojo Property in CSS to reduse size of options in the selection menu.(I added screenshot in to the my first question)

Comment: Set padding for `.dbootstrap .dijitMenuItem`. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to override the dijitTextBox CSS class.

You might need to use CSS specificity to make sure that the CSS is picked up (instead of using !important).

Here's a simple example:

```
.dijitTextBox {
    width: 40px;
    height: 8px;
}
```